# Run macro on selected chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to add a few quick options to the charts in a spreadsheet, I want to select a chart the select/deselect a tick box and the code runs.

The tick box codes is;

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        DisplayLabels    
    Else    
        HideLabels   
    End If

End Sub
```

The DisplayLabels and HideLabels code is

```
Sub DisplayLabels()

    With ActiveChart
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    End With

End Sub

Sub HideLabels()

    With ActiveChart
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Basic_Chart").Activate
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
        Selection.ShowValue = False
    End With

End Sub
```

The problem is that once I tick the box the chart is no longer selected/active and so the code can't work. Is there a way around this. I want this to be re-usable code on multiple sheets so can not directly referent a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the tickbox, have the macro determine if the labels or not. The following will check if a chart is selected, and if, yes, toggle the labels:

```
If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You must select a chart"
    Exit Sub
End If
For Each mySeries In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    On Error Resume Next
    mySeries.DataLabels.Select
    If (Err.Number = 0) Then
        mySeries.DataLabels.Delete
    Else
        mySeries.ApplyDataLabels
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next mySeries
```

Comment: How does this code run?

Comment: If by "How does this code run?" you mean "how do I trigger it?", you can assign it to a button.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, I thought that clicking the button would change focus from the chart to the button, but apparently not. Thanks.